# UIImages do perfectly on iPhone simulator but don't load immediately on real device

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview

I am making an Iphone application which involves a man running across the screen.  However, the image will not load until the player first moves him.  On the iPhone simulator, the image just pops up right from the beginning.  Why could this be?  I set the image at the top of ViewDidLoad
This is the code in -(void)ViewDidLoad:

```
Man.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ManImage.png"];
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: probably not related: [view] is lazy loaded. (ie: view of a UIView wont be created until its .view is first accessed).

Comment: have u tried with perform selectors.....

Answer (score 0):

It happens.

**Step 1:** 
Delete your app on iPhone.

**Step2:**
Do Xcode->Product->Clean and then Run again. You purge old cache that way.